# Ubuntu crashes on Dell LatitudeE5470

Tags: dell

I bought a new dell latitude 5470 with ubuntu. When I start the laptop, it automatically starts the installation process. But the installation crashes in between and it says it will allow me to file a bug report after closing that window. Then the information is being collected. But that stops in the middle and a window.

Screenshot: http://sc.vtiger.net/screenshots/chandu-at-20-24-33.png